# having trouble in pdf conversion using itext

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

This is my Java class for generating PDF. I am using iText for PDF generation.

```
public class pdfgen {
 public void createPdf(String inputFile, String outputFile, boolean isPictureFile)    

 {    
     Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(2780, 2525);    
      Document pdfDoc = new Document(pageSize); 
      String pdfFilePath = outputFile;    
      try  {
          FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath);  
          PdfWriter writer = null;    
          writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDoc, fileOutputStream);
          writer.open(); 
          pdfDoc.open();
          if (isPictureFile){
              pdfDoc.add(com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(inputFile));
          }
          else{
              URL url=new URL(inputFile);
              URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
              String line; while ((line = in.readLine()) !=null ) {
                  System.out.println(line);
              }
              System.out.println(inputFile);
              in.close(); 
              File file = new File(inputFile);
              pdfDoc.add(new  Paragraph(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file)));

          }
          pdfDoc.close();
          writer.close();
      }catch(DocumentException e){
          System.err.println("The error has occured in the document");
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.err.println("Your file is not found.");
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          System.err.println("Exception: "+e);
      }
 }

}
```

This is my JSP file in which I am calling my the above class

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.util.Vector"  %>
<%@page import="com.dalkin.pdfgen" %>
<% Vector result=(Vector)request.getAttribute("val");%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Output </title>
</head>
<body>

<%Vector names; %>
<%if(arrcol.size()!=0){  %>
            <div style="width:1024px;">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

            <tr>                

            <td>
            <%for(int q=0;q<result.size();q+=3){ %>
            <div style="background:url(sample.gif) no-repeat; height:320px; width:500px; float:left;">
            <input type="text" size="50" value=<%=result.get(q) %>>
            <input type="text" size="50" value=  <%=result.get((q+1))%>>    
            <input type="text" size="50" value=<%=result.get((q+2))%>>              
            </div>

            <%}} %>                 
            </td>
            </tr>

</table>
</div>

<%pdfgen pf = new pdfgen();  
pf.createPdf("http://localhost:8080/New/FirstServlet","D:\\first.pdf",false);%>  

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the program I am getting `FileNotFoundException
"http://localhost:8080/New/FirstServlet"
Your file is not found.`
Can anyone help me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You call your PDF creation method like this

```
pf.createPdf("http://localhost:8080/New/FirstServlet","D:\\first.pdf",false);
```

Inside that method you use the first parameter (named inputFile) like this:

```
File file = new File(inputFile);
```

"http://localhost:8080/New/FirstServlet" is no file, so

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(file)
```

is bound to fail with the exception you get.

In the code before you do

```
URL url=new URL(inputFile);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

and then iterate over the lines using line = in.readLine(). Instead of just printing the lines, you could additionally append the lines to some StringBuilder and use the String built in

```
pdfDoc.add(new  Paragraph(...));
```

Comment: You do  StringBuffer temp = null; String line; while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { temp.append(line); }  --- so you use a StringBuffer explicitly set to null. Obviously you will get a NPE.

Comment: Which same error? FNF or NPE? What is your current code?You may want to update your original post accordingly. If you want alternative ways to reach your goal, please do describe properly what you want to achieve.

Comment: So your work flow is 1) someone calls your JSP page, 2) the JSP page builds some table (BTW, your arrcol does not seem to be defined anywhere), 3) the JSP page triggers your createPdf method to create some PDF, 4) createPdf connects to a local local web service (in the same web container? In a different one?) represented by FirstServlet, 5) that web service creates some clear text response, 6) createPdf creates a PDF from that text and stores it locally, and 7) your JSP page returns some HTML. What parts of the flow are actual requirements and what parts are arbitrary implementation choices?

Comment: Does that mean the URL http://localhost:8080/New/FirstServlet in the createPdf call at the end of your JSP is the URL of the JSP itself?

Comment: Ok, so the user accesses New.jsp. New.jsp posts to FirstServlet. FirstServlet forwards the request to NewFile1.jsp. which I assume to be the JSP you originally posted. So NewFile1.jsp calls createPdf for "http://localhost:8080/New/FirstServlet". So FirstServlet is accessed again, but this time using GET, the Default method. This circularity might be unwanted by your servlet container and give rise to some exception. If it doesn't, createPdf retrieves an empty answer as you have only an empty doGet implementation. But this circularity really is not good design.